# Windows 10 Sound Lower Than Before Re-installing Windows

Tags: windows-10

Recently I reinstalled windows 10 on my computer to wipe the computer as the storage was quite full!

After reinstalling windows, my sound has dropped like 75%!

I have looked on other threads on superuser, but none have helped.

I have tried checking communications, enabling super-sonic headphones, and a few others I've seen.

I use realtek hd audio.

EDIT: I also have communications set to do nothing.

Comment: sympathies... sound settings in Win10 are the worst. can you elaborate on what you did to "check levels"? exactly which settings have you checked?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I had checked the communications section and it was set to do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I'm an idiot.
Thanks gronostaj for reminding me to check the volume mixer...

Sorry for wasting your time.

EDIT:
For all future people visiting this in the future, right click the sound icon on your taskbar and click volume mixer.
Then play sound on the program with low sound.
Go back into the volume mixer and make sure the volume is full/set to the current total system volume.

Comment: Will accept this comment in 17 hours once it lets me.

Comment: Just before Halloween (i.e., in a little over eight weeks), all the comments will be deleted.   On November 1, somebody with the same problem (and maybe a little less background knowledge) will find this page through a search.   Please [edit] your answer to contain all the information that that new person will need to solve their situation.

Comment: I am very surprised that an entirely fresh install left a volume mixer with variable settings. Nonetheless, I will delete my answer because it now does not fit.